How can I center-align a HeaderAttribute in a Unity custom inspector / can it be done simply?
So far, this is the only resource I've found that does what I'm looking to do (which is to center-align my inspector headers): CreatureSurvive's example script on GitHub Gist
If I'm understanding properly, the center alignment is achieved either through the depth field,
/// <param name="depth">the depth of this header element in the inspector foldout</param>

or through what appear to be style fields, like padding, margin, etc.,
// draw header background and label
var headerRect = new Rect(pos.x + margin, pos.y + spacing, 
                         (pos.width - margin) + (padding * 2), 
                          pos.height - (spacing + barHeight + spacing));
EditorGUI.DrawRect(headerRect, Constants.BackgroundColor);

This appears to be an example result using the linked script:

More to the point, ignoring some of the fancier adjustments to the editor in the image above:

Is it necessary to write a custom script in this manner to be able to adjust the alignments of  HeaderAttributes?
Are there any functions of something like EditorGUILayout that could handle the alignment of attributes (instead of having to write a script that does the same thing)?



The [Header] attribute is intended to be a simple, utilitarian solution for headers. It does not support any advanced formatting such as adjusting the alignment of the header. If you want a more customizable header, you would need an Attribute class and PropertyDrawer, as in the example you linked to.

Layout functions can be used inside a custom PropertyDrawer or Editor. They can't be used to adjust the layout of existing attributes like [Header]


